# recording the passed value in a function call in R

Tags: r, function, tidyeval

When I write call a function, I would like to record in the output of the function one or more of the parameters that were passed to the function. When the function parameter points to another object, I can't figure out how to do that. I've tried various combinations of `quo` and `expr` etc...but seem to be missing the exact syntax to pass a string variable into a data.frame as follows:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 awesomedf <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b= "hihi")
 
 myfunction <- function(usedata = awesomedf){
   usedata %>% 
     summarize(meancol1 = mean(a)) %>% 
     mutate(datasetused = deparse(substitute(usedata)))
 }
 
 myfunction()
```

Returns:

```
  meancol1 datasetused
1        3     usedata
```

What I would like to see is:

```
  meancol1 datasetused
1        3     awesomedf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `deparse/substitute` at the top to capture it before it becomes an evaluated expression

```
myfunction <- function(usedata = awesomedf){ 
val <- deparse(substitute(usedata))
  usedata %>% 
    summarize(meancol1 = mean(a)) %>% 
  mutate(datasetused = val)
 }
```

-testing

```
myfunction()
#   meancol1 datasetused
#1        3   awesomedf
```